# Shopify webhook application

Tags: shopify, webhooks

I was thinking of implementing a shopify application.the purpose of application is that when it is installed on any store.**Application would set the HTTP POST request URL itself** and when there is any order placed on that store,App will send us the information via POST.

Is that possible using webhooks?
beacuse i cant find any way to programattically using the webhooks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read the API docs for webhooks? All it talks about is using them programmatically.

http://docs.shopify.com/api/webhooks/using-webhooks

Are you running into some specific issue?

Comment: Yes i had read the docs but they are all about intercepting the HTTP POST request.you have to enter the URL (on which notification is sent) manually.

Comment: No you don't. The page John linked to talks about the management of Webhook subscriptions. [Here's the specific section that talks about subscription creation](http://api.shopify.com/webhook.html#create). Both John and I are Shopify developers who work with the API daily, you can trust us when we say you can do this :)